# React state only update after second time being executed

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-hooks

I had this problem for a while and can't find a solution.

I'm trying to change the state to complex data.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(null)

function Save(){
    if(state){
        setState((prev)=>[...prev, [p1, p2, p3, p4]])
    }else{
        setState([[p1, p2, p3, p4]])
    }
}
```

First when I call the `Save()` function the state is changed correctly

```
Array [
  Array [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
]
```

But at the second run, I get the same state

```
Array [
  Array [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
]
```

After that everything works correctly fine and the state is added

```
Array [
  Array [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
  Array [
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ],
  ....
]
```

here is the full code

```
export default function ModalForm({close}) {
    const { state, setState } = useStateContext()
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    const [p1, setP1] = useState('')
    const [p2, setP2] = useState('')
    const [p3, setP3] = useState('')
    const [p4, setP4] = useState('')

    const [v1, setV1] = useState('')
    const [v2, setV2] = useState('')
    const [v3, setV3] = useState('')
    const [v4, setV4] = useState('')
    const [v5, setV5] = useState('')

    async function Save(){
        setState((prev) => {
            if (prev) {
                let id = state.length
                return([...prev, [name, id, p1, p2, p3, p4, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]])
            } else {
                return([[name, 0, p1, p2, p3, p4, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]])
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <Pressable style={styles.centeredView} onPress={() => close()}>
            <ScrollView>
                <Pressable style={styles.modalView} onPress={() => console.log('hi')}>
                    <Text style={styles.modalText}>Make new!</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
                        value={name}
                        placeholder="Name"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setP1(text)}
                        value={p1}
                        placeholder="Period 1"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setP2(text)}
                        value={p2}
                        placeholder="Period 2"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setP3(text)}
                        value={p3}
                        placeholder="Period 3"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setP4(text)}
                        value={p4}
                        placeholder="Period 4"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setV1(text)}
                        value={v1}
                        placeholder="Voltage 1"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setV2(text)}
                        value={v2}
                        placeholder="Voltage 2"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setV3(text)}
                        value={v3}
                        placeholder="Voltage 3"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setV4(text)}
                        value={v4}
                        placeholder="Voltage 4"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        textAlign='center'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={text => setV5(text)}
                        value={v5}
                        placeholder="Voltage 5"
                    />
                    <Pressable
                        style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
                        onPress={() => {
                            Save()
                            close()
                        }}>
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Save</Text>
                    </Pressable>
                </Pressable>
            </ScrollView>
        </Pressable>
    )
}
```

and the state is displayed in a flat List who looks like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={state}
    renderItem={Item}
    keyExtractor={item => item[1]}
    ListEmptyComponent={Empty}    
    styles={styles.container}     
    />
```

added the change from the first answer

Comment: You aren't showing how you're, well, showing this data. Remember `setState` is asynchronous; reading `state` right after calling `setState` won't show an updated value.

Comment: I call the function 3 separate times

Comment: Yes, but where do you get the "Array [ Array [ ... ]" you're showing here?

Comment: Ie: where is your `console.log` statement?

Comment: this is just to illustrate the behavior. the real code is supposed to render this state as a button on the screen

Comment: Can you share the full code? where exactly you are calling Save()?

Comment: Yes, I can. I edit the post so you can see the full code! you can find the save function under the wast text input in the pressable components onPress method

Comment: Where, or how, exactly are you verifying the state updates? It seems none of us here see any overt issues with this specific code, so if you are saying there's an issue *somewhere* then please show us exactly where you are seeing the issue. Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use the previous state to evaluate what the new state will be, you should wrap it in the functional state update form, which passes the previous state as the first parameter to the function. Use that parameter, NOT the current state, to evaluate whatever you need to evaluate that relies on the current state. In your example, you need to make the following change:

```
function Save() {
    setState((prev) => {
        if (prev) {
            return [...prev, [p1, p2, p3, p4]]
        } else {
            return [[p1, p2, p3, p4]]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: setState inside setState?

Comment: the behavior is still the same

Comment: should call return instead of setState indeed, the updater function needs to return the new state

Comment: I did it but the behavior is still the same

Comment: @VladimirKutsev After seeing your full code, I noticed you are using a third-party library to handle your state, and I'm not familiar with how that works internally, but this solution will work for the `useState` hook provided by React. If you combine it with React Context or simply passing that state around where it is needed, it should solve your problem.